# Use of unresolved identifier 'SignUp' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Below is the code, hope anyone can help me solve the `Use of unresolved identifier 'SignUp'` problem:

```
@IBOutlet var UsernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var PasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var EmailTextField: UITextField!
@IBAction func LogIn(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func Signup(sender: AnyObject) {
   SignUp() //Error is here.
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

func SignUp(){
    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = UsernameTextField.text
    user.password = PasswordTextField.text
    user.email = EmailTextField.text
}

let user = PFUser()
user.username = "Name:"
user.password = "Pass:"
user.email = "Email:"

user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
if error == nil {
   // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
   } else {
   // Examine the error object and inform the user.
   }
}
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: The general convention is to use lowerCamelCase for properties and methods to distinguish them from UpperCamelCase types, such as structs and classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the function declaration and call start with a lower case s.

It's also worth noting you should name stuff so it's clear what is it.

```
@IBAction func signUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {
   signUp() // Calling signUp function here that is declared below.
}


func signUp(){
    // Do sign up stuff.
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I dont understand what you meant by  'Make the function declaration'

Comment: @ArcadeMaestrex I've edited my answer, hope it helps.